# SQL query to find the common data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 with columns `serial, ida, idb`, and `remark`.

Example data :

```
serial   ida      idb      remark
1        3        4        null
2        3        6        null
3        3        7        null
4        2        3        null
5        4        7        null
6        4        6        null
```

I want to select the common `idb` from `ida` 3 and 4. I am confused here how to write the SQL query for this.

A little help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you give us your desired output?

Comment: Not sure but I think either he is looking for result 6,7 (intersection) OR 4,6,7 (Union). OP needs to mention that.

Comment: i am luking for 6,7 .. intersection will do thnx

Comment: output will help us in provide you proper results, but with respect to your question @joHn Dewey is right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select idb from mytable
Where ida = 3
intersect
Select idb from mytable
Where ida = 4
```

Comment: what does the intersect operator stands for

Comment: i need to do inner join with some table with the selected data. will it be posible

Comment: In you case, intersection will return you the result 6,7. take a look here ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)

Comment: Returns a distinct list of results common to both queries. So if the first query returns 4,6,7, and the second returns 6,7, the intersect will return 6,7 because 6,7 is common to both queries.

Comment: but as soon as we add another column in the query along with ida, result set changes.. we cannot selected any other information except idb column

Comment: @biplob: it's all very well documented on [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) - freely available to anyone

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.idb
FROM mytable AS t1, mytable AS t2
WHERE t1.ida = 3 AND t2.ida = 4 AND t1.idb = t2.idb
```

Comment: you have showed the correct answer here as we can select otehr columns in the table along with the common data..